# wit.ai with Microsoft Bot Builder

Tags: botframework

The Microsoft Bot builder uses **LUIS** Dialog as the only option for natural language processing.
Can we use **wit.ai** with Microsoft Bot builder. Is it available out of the box?
If the answer is NO, Is there a way where we can also use wit.ai for the natural language processing.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am still in the very early stages, but you can have a look on my Wit.ai integration with BotBuilder

https://github.com/q3blend/BotBuilder-Wit.ai

Answer (score 2):

wit.ai is currently not supported out of the box.

If you wanted to implement this functionality yourself, you would start from their [HTTP API Documentation](https://wit.ai/docs/http/20160526).

You didn't mention whether you are using Bot Builder for Node.JS or for .NET. For Node.JS, the [LUISRecognizer](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/Node/core/src/dialogs/LuisRecognizer.ts) could be a good starting point to build your own Recognizer. This is useful for natural language understanding that maps well to the "single Intent with Entities" model LUIS uses. The other, more flexible option, is just creating a [SimpleDialog](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/classes/_botbuilder_d_.simpledialog.html) with a single handler function that calls wit.ai .

Feel free to also vote for [this related feature request](https://feedback.botframework.com/forums/354222-bot-builder-sdk/suggestions/13494474--nocejs-add-a-wit-ai-dialog-class-similar-to-luis)!

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. I am using Bot Builder for .NET

Answer (score 2):

There's a nice NPM module to use Wit.ai with Bot Framework for Node: **botbuilder-wit**. But, as it wasn't updated for months, **I made a fork with some corrections**: https://github.com/Joffrey4/botbuilder-wit.

And for the .NET version, there's [BotBuilder-Wit.ai](https://github.com/q3blend/BotBuilder-Wit.ai). But I didn't tested it personally.